# How to insert the dataframe values to MySQL db in python

Tags: python, mysql, numpy, dataframe

Result is my dataframe with values. I didnt get any error but i am not able to view the data in the db. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import warnings
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import sys
import MySQLdb as MySQLdb
import math
from pandas.io import sql
import mysql.connector
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql as pymysql 

engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://user:pass@rds.amazonaws.com/testSchema"
                       .format(user="*******",
                               pw="*******",
                               db="testSchema"))
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="rds.amazonaws.com",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="user",         # your username
                     password="pass",  # your password
                     database="testSchema")   


result.to_sql(name='bucketFillTest',con=engine,if_exists='replace',index=False) 

db.close()
```

Comment: You may want to change your database credentials on your db server. Even though they've been edited out, people can see the edit history.